# How to evaluate the integral defined below analytically,

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to integrate $\int_0^{\Omega}\sqrt{\log(1+1/\theta)}d\theta$ whenever $\Omega$ is very small.

Comment: If I consider $f(x) = \sqrt{\log(1+\frac{1}{x})}$ then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$ which would imply that the your integral will tend to $\infty$ for small value of $\Omega$ unless $\Omega$ is $0$ in which case the integral will be $0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @expiTT--I--1z0: That means nothing: $\lim _{x \to 0^+} \frac 1 {\sqrt x} = \infty$, yet $\int _0 ^\Omega \frac 1 {\sqrt x} \ \Bbb d x = 2 \sqrt \Omega$ which is finite for all $\Omega \ge 0$. This shows that a function may be unbounded near a point, yet its integral around that point may be finite.

Comment: Ahh that's correct. Silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the double inequality (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm)) $$1-\frac 1t \leq \log(t)\leq t-1$$  which makes $$\frac 1{\sqrt{x+1}}\leq \sqrt{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\leq \frac 1{\sqrt{x}}$$ So, integrating $$\int_0^y\frac {dx}{\sqrt{x+1}}\leq \int_0^y\sqrt{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\,dx\leq \int_0^y\frac {dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$ $$2 \sqrt{y+1}-2\leq \int_0^y\sqrt{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\,dx\leq 2 \sqrt{y}$$ I do not see what more could be done (at least by myself).